# How to set expiration for runtimeCaching in Workbox generateSW()?

Tags: progressive-web-apps, service-worker, workbox

I'm trying to set the expiration for assets in my runtimeCaching. As an example I have this:

```
    {
        // https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js
        urlPattern: /^https:\/\/code\.jquery\.com\/jquery-3\.5\.1.*/,
        handler: 'CacheFirst',
        options: {
            cacheName: 'external-assets',
            cacheableResponse: {
                statuses: [0, 200]
            },
            cacheExpiration: {
                maxAgeSeconds: 60 * 60 * 24 * 14, // 2 Week
                maxEntries: 1
            }
        }
    },
```

In the console when I try running generateSW() via an NPM script, I get:

```
> ispot@0.1.0 sw
> node sw_build.js

[Error [ValidationError]: "runtimeCaching[0].options.cacheExpiration" is not allowed] {
  _original: {
    swDest: './public/service-worker.js',
    skipWaiting: true,
    clientsClaim: true,
    cleanupOutdatedCaches: true,
    mode: 'development',
    runtimeCaching: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  details: [
    {
      message: '"runtimeCaching[0].options.cacheExpiration" is not allowed',
      path: [Array],
      type: 'object.unknown',
      context: [Object]
    }
  ]
}
```

Finding it hard to find documentation on Workbox's site for how to set this up for generateSW().

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer here:

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/generate-service-worker/workbox-build

The object key is expiration, not cacheExpiration...

```
expiration: {
   maxAgeSeconds: 60 * 60 * 24 * 14, // 2 Week
   maxEntries: 100
}
```